# Is there any way to reduce the binary size when implementing a major ad newtork in iOS (AdMob, MoPub, Facebook Audience Network, etc.)?

Tags: ios, ads

Since Apple discontinued support for iAd I have looked into implementing other ad networks in my iOS app. However, each network has a fairly large (~50 MB) framework that must be linked to the app, which would greatly increase the size of my previously 5 MB app. I have also considered using mediation to increase my revenue, but this would result in an even larger binary.

Looking into these frameworks, it appears that the majority of their contents is related to Native and Video ads, even though I am only using banner ads. Has anyone found a way to use one or more ad networks in iOS without drastically increasing the size of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation I realized that the binary was actually only 38 MB with multiple ad frameworks, which is much more reasonable. I had previously looked at the size of the archive, which was significantly larger than the binary itself.